# Angular2 Typescript Typings Duplicate identifier

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular, asp.net-core, typescript-typings

Have seen other posts but none of the suggested solutions there worked.
So I still see these duplicate identifier errors even though I excluded the whole `typings` folder. `typings` folder is in the same level of `node_modules` and `bower_components` folder

Here's my typings.json as suggested by Angular 2:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

What do I need to do? :(

PS: I uninstalled the TypeScript for Visual Studio which is version 1.8.6 and just used the npm typescript which is 1.8.10. Previously, they were installed together in my machine but still not works.

[image]

Comment: Did you add a new `npm` package dependency recently, if so sometimes they can use the `///` directive to reference other files in `node_modules` - I know that I fought this same issue with later versions of **TypeScript**. The issue is that some packages ship `.ts` files, and as a result with this "outreach" from the reference in the `///` **TypeScript** finds things multiple times.

Comment: actually this is a new project. but i also excluded the npm_modules folder. shouldn't they be not included during the compilation also?

Comment: are you using webpack bundle in gulp?

Comment: you definitely **don't** want to exclude your entire typings folder in tsconfig, but that's not causing your problem. Your typings folder looks suspicious though: `bootstrap.d.ts` and the other files in the top level - how did those get there? My hunch is you c/p'd them manually, and that if you remove them and install properly via `typings install` your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typings are really strange, you should have either `es6-shim` or `core-js`, not both of them. `node` is most probably redundant too.

Personally, i gave up on VS and plugged angular using gulp build file.

Comment: corejs, jasmine and node are the ones seen on angular2 getting started example. i'll try to remove es6shim

Comment: Check this discussion for more information https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5755

Comment: ok so in my typings.json, i'll try to use corejs only. whats in ur typings?

Comment: i have `es6-shim` only.

Comment: need to go to work now. will test it later. but if this works out, i will  edit that sample >_<

Answer (score 1):

Your exclude isn't right. Assuming you are using Typings version 1.0 or later, it should look like this given the screen shot you added.

```js
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/modules"
  ],
```

Comment: thanks, i just realized it also... but partially correct since i only use 0.8. for lower versions,      
"exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "bower_components",
 -     "typings"
      "typings/browser/ambient",
      "typings/main/ambient",
     "typings/browser.d.ts",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
     ]